# {Laravel} How to display badge reach message? qcod/laravel-gamify

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I will ask about this Plugin
I'm having trouble showing badge.
For Question, this Badge Controller code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Gamify\Badges;
use QCod\Gamify\BadgeType;
class FirstRewards extends BadgeType
{
    /**
     * Description for badge
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'You Archieved Badges "First Reward"';

    /**
     * Check is user qualifies for badge
     *
     * @param $user
     * @return bool
     */
    public function qualifier($user)
    {
        return $user->getPoints() >= 1000;
    }
}
```

Then how do I display a message that I have reached the point to get a badge?
I want to use messages like this

```
public function message(){
session()->flash('message', 'You got your rewards!');
Session::flash('type', 'success');
Session::flash('title', 'Level Up!');
return(redirect()->route('index');
}
```

Is there an effective way for me to apply it?